# Getting exception while using REST API

Tags: android, rest, android-studio, gson

I got an error of Expected `Begin_ARRAY`. but was `BEGIN_OBJECTS` at line  **1 column**

I am trying to get data from URL into recyclerview

```
 api = RetrofitClient.getApiClient().create(Api.class);

    Call<List<Courses>> call = api.getallcourse();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Courses>>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Courses>> call, Response<List<Courses>> response) {
            Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, ""+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            courses = response.body();
            recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(courses);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Courses>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, ""+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
```

Comment: public static Retrofit retrofits = null;

    public static Retrofit getApiClient(){
        if (retrofits == null){
            retrofits = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).
                    addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }
        return retrofits;
    }

Comment: your response of API is not a list it self